# NameError: global name 'lower' is not defined

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm doing a word count program in PySpark, but every time I go to run it, I get the following error:

```
NameError: global name 'lower' is not defined
```

These two lines are what's giving me the problem:

```
wordsCount = words.map(lambda word: (word,lower(), 1)) \
.reduceByKey(lambda numOfWord1, numOfWord2: numOfWord1 + numOfWord2) \
    .map(lambda word: (word[0],word[1], word[1]/float(total_words)))

charsCount = chars.map(lambda char: (char.lower(), 1)) \
.reduceByKey(lambda numOfchar1, numOfchar2: numOfchar1 + numOfchar2)
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank You!

Answer (score -1):

To get the lowercase version of word, use `word.lower()` instead of `word,lower()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been staring at this for so long, and I haven't been able to figure it out. Such a careless mistake.